# Optimize SQL query plan Informix

Tags: informix

```
create view "informix".v_prod_cost (ship_no,dc_id,whse_id,cust_id,prod_id,
          unit_cost_excl,unit_cost_incl,vat_perc,is_catch_wght,tot_cost_excl,tot_cost_incl) as 
  SELECT x3.ship_no, x1.dc_id, x1.whse_id, x4.cust_id, x1.prod_id, 
    x5.case_cost, round(((x5.case_cost * (x7.cvat_desc ::smallint 
    + 100. ) ) / 100.0000000000000000 ) , 2 ), x7.cvat_desc,
    CASE WHEN ((x4.catch_wgt_ctl = 'Y' ) AND (x5.catch_wgt_cntl 
    = 'Y' ) )  THEN 'Y'  WHEN ((x4.catch_wgt_ctl = 'N' ) AND (x5.catch_wgt_cntl 
    = 'Y' ) )  THEN 'N'  ELSE 'N'  END,
    CASE WHEN ((x4.catch_wgt_ctl 
    = 'Y' ) AND (x5.catch_wgt_cntl = 'Y' ) )  THEN round(sum((select 
    (sum(x9.catch_wgt ) * x5.case_cost ) from "informix".icwma 
    x8 ,"informix".icwmad x9 where (((((((((((x8.cwma_id = x9.cwma_id 
    ) AND (x8.dc_id = x1.dc_id ) ) AND (x8.whse_id = x1.whse_id 
    ) ) AND (x8.curr_pal_no = x1.curr_pal_no ) ) AND (x8.ord_id 
    = x1.ord_id ) ) AND (x8.prod_id = x1.prod_id ) ) AND (x8.invc_id 
    = x1.invc_id ) ) AND (x8.sgmt_id = x1.sgmt_id ) ) AND (x8.unit_ship_cse 
    = x1.unit_ship_cse ) ) AND (x8.assg_id = x1.assg_id ) ) AND 
    (x8.ckpt_id = x1.ckpt_id ) ) ) ) , 2 )  WHEN ((x4.catch_wgt_ctl 
    = 'N' ) AND (x5.catch_wgt_cntl = 'Y' ) )  THEN round(sum((((x1.prod_qty 
    / x1.unit_ship_cse ) * x1.prod_wgt ) * x5.case_cost ) ) ,
     2 )  ELSE round(sum((x1.prod_qty * x5.case_cost ) ) , 2 
    )  END,
    CASE WHEN ((x4.catch_wgt_ctl = 'Y' ) AND (x5.catch_wgt_cntl 
    = 'Y' ) )  THEN round(sum((select (((sum(x11.catch_wgt ) * 
    x5.case_cost ) * (x7.cvat_desc ::smallint + 100. ) ) / 100.0000000000000000 
    ) from "informix".icwma x10 ,"informix".icwmad x11 where (((((((((((x10.cwma_id 
    = x11.cwma_id ) AND (x10.dc_id = x1.dc_id ) ) AND (x10.whse_id 
    = x1.whse_id ) ) AND (x10.curr_pal_no = x1.curr_pal_no ) 
    ) AND (x10.ord_id = x1.ord_id ) ) AND (x10.prod_id = x1.prod_id 
    ) ) AND (x10.invc_id = x1.invc_id ) ) AND (x10.sgmt_id = 
    x1.sgmt_id ) ) AND (x10.unit_ship_cse = x1.unit_ship_cse 
    ) ) AND (x10.assg_id = x1.assg_id ) ) AND (x10.ckpt_id = 
    x1.ckpt_id ) ) ) ) , 2 )  WHEN ((x4.catch_wgt_ctl = 'N' ) 
    AND (x5.catch_wgt_cntl = 'Y' ) )  THEN round(sum(((((x1.prod_qty 
    / x1.unit_ship_cse ) * x1.prod_wgt ) * x5.case_cost ) * (x7.cvat_desc 
    ::smallint + 100. ) ) ) , 2 )  ELSE round(sum((((x1.prod_qty 
    * x5.case_cost ) * (x7.cvat_desc ::smallint + 100. ) ) / 
    100.0000000000000000 ) ) , 2 )  END
  FROM "informix".ishs x0, 
       "informix".ishd x1, "informix".irtst x2, "informix".crtst x3,
       "informix".icust x4, "informix".iprod x5, "informix".cprod x6,
       "informix".cvat x7
 WHERE ((((((((((((x0.shs_id = x1.shs_id 
    ) AND (x0.dc_id = x1.dc_id ) ) AND (x0.whse_id = x1.dc_id 
    ) ) AND (x0.rtst_id = x2.rtst_id ) ) AND (x0.dc_id = x2.dc_id 
    ) ) AND (x1.whse_id = x2.dc_id ) ) AND (x2.rtst_id = x3.rtst_id 
    ) ) AND (x1.cust_id = x4.cust_id ) ) AND (x1.dc_id = x5.dc_id 
    ) ) AND (x1.prod_id = x5.prod_id ) ) AND (x5.prod_id = x6.prod_id 
    ) ) AND (x6.vat_ind = x7.vat_ind ) )
GROUP BY x3.ship_no, x1.dc_id, x1.whse_id, x4.cust_id, x1.prod_id,
    x5.case_cost, 7, x7.cvat_desc, 9, x4.catch_wgt_ctl, x5.catch_wgt_cntl 
    ;
```

I have the view above, which was created to perform the necessary calculations. The problem I am facing it takes over 5 minutes to run.

This is my sql trace output:

```
IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC4W1WE -- On-Line -- Up 27 days 20:42:31 -- 2211344 Kbytes

Statement history:

Trace Level                  High
Trace Mode                   User
Number of traces             1000
Current Stmt ID                 1
Trace Buffer size            4056
Duration of buffer     1481025737 Seconds
Trace Flags            0x0000FF21
Control Block          700000015dc1028



Statement # 1:     @ 700000015dc1048

 Database:        system                                                      
 Statement text:
  select * from v_prod_cost

  SELECT using tables [ ishs ishd irtst crtst icust iprod cprod cvat ]

 Iterator/Explain    
 ================    
    ID   Left  Right Sender   Next   Est Cost   Est Rows   Num Rows    Partnum Type      
     9      0      0      0      0      10054      47203      47203    7342066 Seq Scan
    10      0      0      0      0          1      40977          1    7340184 Index Scan
     8      9     10      0      0      35212      40977      40715          0 Nested Join
    11      0      0      0      0          2     325474          6    7343766 Index Scan
     7      8     11      0      0     154765     278608     303217          0 Nested Join
    12      0      0      0      0          1    1280461          1    7343819 Index Scan
     6      7     12      0      0     550996    1111035    1225518          0 Nested Join
    13      0      0      0      0          1     152406          1    7340237 Index Scan
     5      6     13      0      0    1337728    1111035    1225518          0 Nested Join
    14      0      0      0      0          2          2          2    7340235 Seq Scan
     4      5     14      0      0    1544660    1111032    1225518          0 Hash Join
    15      0      0      0      0          1       6941          1    7343796 Index Scan
     3      4     15      0      0    2084251    1111036    1225518          0 Nested Join
    16      0      0      0      0          1     152627          1    7341873 Index Scan
     2      3     16      0      0    3736185    1109418    1225518          0 Nested Join
     1      2      0      0      0    2892742    1108253         27          0 Group

 Statement information:
  Sess_id  User_id  Stmt Type        Finish Time    Run Time   TX Stamp   PDQ 
  207705   55121    SELECT           14:02:16       99.8398    cd5d6ee8   0   

 Statement Statistics:
  Page       Buffer     Read       Buffer     Page       Buffer     Write     
  Read       Read       % Cache    IDX Read   Write      Write      % Cache   
  0          18720195   100.00     0          87400      704        0.00      

  Lock       Lock       LK Wait    Log        Num        Disk       Memory    
  Requests   Waits      Time (S)   Space      Sorts      Sorts      Sorts     
  10561863   0          0.0000     0.000 B    0          0          0         

  Total      Total      Avg        Max        Avg        I/O Wait   Avg Rows  
  Executions Time (S)   Time (S)   Time (S)   IO Wait    Time (S)   Per Sec   
  1          99.8398    99.8398    99.8398    0.000000   0.000000   0.2704    

  Estimated  Estimated  Actual     SQL        ISAM       Isolation  SQL       
  Cost       Rows       Rows       Error      Error      Level      Memory    
  6628928    1108253    27         0          0          CR         331184    

The below is my SET EXPLAIN output:

QUERY: (OPTIMIZATION TIMESTAMP: 12-06-2016 14:12:43)
------
select * from v_prod_cost


Estimated Cost: 6628928
Estimated # of Rows Returned: 1108253
Temporary Files Required For: Group By 

  1) informix.irtst: SEQUENTIAL SCAN

  2) informix.crtst: INDEX PATH

    (1) Index Name: informix. 1565_316639
        Index Keys: rtst_id   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
        Lower Index Filter: informix.irtst.rtst_id = informix.crtst.rtst_id 
NESTED LOOP JOIN

  3) informix.ishs: INDEX PATH

        Filters: (informix.ishs.dc_id = informix.irtst.dc_id AND informix.ishs.dc_id = informix.ishs.whse_id ) 

    (1) Index Name: informix.ishs_rtst
        Index Keys: rtst_id   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
        Lower Index Filter: informix.ishs.rtst_id = informix.crtst.rtst_id 
NESTED LOOP JOIN

  4) informix.ishd: INDEX PATH

        Filters: (informix.ishs.whse_id = informix.ishd.dc_id AND informix.ishd.dc_id = informix.ishd.whse_id ) 

    (1) Index Name: informix.ishdd1
        Index Keys: shs_id   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
        Lower Index Filter: informix.ishs.shs_id = informix.ishd.shs_id 
NESTED LOOP JOIN

  5) informix.cprod: INDEX PATH

    (1) Index Name: informix.cprodu1
        Index Keys: prod_id   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
        Lower Index Filter: informix.ishd.prod_id = informix.cprod.prod_id 
NESTED LOOP JOIN

  6) informix.cvat: SEQUENTIAL SCAN


DYNAMIC HASH JOIN 
    Dynamic Hash Filters: informix.cprod.vat_ind = informix.cvat.vat_ind 

  7) informix.icust: INDEX PATH

    (1) Index Name: informix.icustu1
        Index Keys: cust_id   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
        Lower Index Filter: informix.ishd.cust_id = informix.icust.cust_id 
NESTED LOOP JOIN

  8) informix.iprod: INDEX PATH

    (1) Index Name: informix. 588_2002
        Index Keys: prod_id dc_id   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
        Lower Index Filter: (informix.iprod.prod_id = informix.cprod.prod_id AND informix.ishs.whse_id = informix.iprod.dc_id ) 
NESTED LOOP JOIN


Query statistics:
-----------------

  Table map :
  ----------------------------
  Internal name     Table name
  ----------------------------
  t1                irtst
  t2                crtst
  t3                ishs
  t4                ishd
  t5                cprod
  t6                cvat
  t7                icust
  t8                iprod

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t1     47203      47203     47203      00:00.10   10054   

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t2     40715      40977     40715      00:00.41   1       

  type     rows_prod  est_rows  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------
  nljoin   40715      40978     00:00.53   35213   

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t3     303217     325474    303217     00:01.35   3       

  type     rows_prod  est_rows  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------
  nljoin   303217     278609    00:01.94   154765  

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t4     1225518    1280461   1225518    00:07.02   1       

  type     rows_prod  est_rows  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------
  nljoin   1225518    1111035   00:09.22   550996  

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t5     1225518    152406    1225518    00:11.75   1       

  type     rows_prod  est_rows  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------
  nljoin   1225518    1111036   00:21.40   1337728 

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t6     2          2         2          00:00.00   2       

  type     rows_prod  est_rows  rows_bld  rows_prb  novrflo  time       est_cost
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  hjoin    1225518    1111033   2         1225518   0        00:25.94   1544661 

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t7     1225518    6941      1225518    00:09.50   0       

  type     rows_prod  est_rows  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------
  nljoin   1225518    1111037   00:35.99   2084251 

  type     table  rows_prod  est_rows  rows_scan  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  scan     t8     1225518    152627    1225518    00:12.24   1       

  type     rows_prod  est_rows  time       est_cost
  -------------------------------------------------
  nljoin   1225518    1109418   00:48.97   3736186 

  type     rows_prod  est_rows  rows_cons  time       est_cost
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  group    27         1108253   1225518    01:42.95   2892742
```

What can I do to reduce the cost of nested loops and dynamics hash joins?

Comment: That's almost unreadable!

Comment: You have some sub-selects in the main select-list.  Those are not going to reduce the cost of the query.  The formatting — which looks like what you get from the view definition in the system catalog — is horrendous.  It's not your fault that it uses space-comma instead of comma-space except where I've changed it.  (I'd love to scrag the person who botched that part of the formatting!)  The expressions in the select-list are very difficult to read.  I'm not sure what the benefit of 100.000000000000 is compared to, say, 100.0.  What is the query calculating?  What do you use as the CREATE VIEW?